# problems getting locale to execute on command line

Tags: windows, cmd, locale

If I conduct the below three steps in a English version of Windows 7, the local will execute as desired:

1. Open the cmd
2. Go to directory 'C:\Windows\System32>'
3. type 'locale' into the command line

However, if I do the exact same steps in a Spanish version of Windows 7, I get the following error message:

- ""locale" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable."

which seems to be translated to English as:

- 'xyzRandom' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.

I cannot understand why locale will not execute in the Spanish OS.  The file, locale.nls does exist in directory C:\Windows\System32> in the Spanish version of Windows so it is not as if the file goes by a different name when using a Spanish os.
Does anyone know why the locale command would not work on the Spanish command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the locale command was coming from Cygwin, not from cmd.  I had Cygwin installed on my Computer and additionally had added c:\cygwin\bin to the PATH environment variable.  Therefore, the cmd was picking up the locale command from the Cygwin bin, not from C:\Windows\System32.  Once I installed Cygwin onto the machine with the Spanish OS, the locale command operated as expected.  The picture below shows typical output from the locale command ...

[image]

You can change the output of the locale command by changing the value of one of the LC_ variables as shown below ...

[image]

As far as I can tell, this seems to have no affect on how any program (installed on windows) operates or what locale is used by a program by default.  C.UTF8 still seems to be the default locale used by software even if the value of locale is changed to something other than C.UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

There is truly no reason why this should happen.
There are 2 options: 
You are using a Windows Crack or your Windows files are corrupted.

Comment: the Spanish OS version was thrown together for testing ... I believe from a ghost image.  It was installed on a clean machine just today so is shouldn't be corrupt (although a possibility I suppose).

Comment: If the windows file were corrupt (the language, locale files), I am pretty sure I would have a lot more problems on the OS than just not being able to execute the 'locale' command on the cmd.